# confused with MVC in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I have a small slots game almost developed for iPad as this is my very first interaction with any of Apple technology, so I never really designed this application properly while developing, I want to mould this code into, what apple advocates, `Model-View-Controller` style. I read a lot about it but still confused.
This is what I have:

1. ViewController class created by
   default
2. Some methods to control the
   animation
3. Textiles for some data and some
   methods to access them
4. Methods to calculate payouts and
   winning amounts

So what should I exactly do now to convert it into MVC, how should my approach be?
Also tell me any good books or online documentation for the same

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Read Cocoa Core Competencies http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1 and Cocoa Fundamentals Guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model should represent the state of your game at any time, but not in a visual sense. Think of it as the game logic. So it would have current score, current state of slot reels etc. The model would also be responsible for "spinning the reels"

The view is a visual representation of that model, you can render that information in any way you like, 3D, 2D etc and it makes no difference, the model is the same (this is the real benefit to MVC).

Your controller (commonly a Viewcontroller in iOS) mediates between the model and controller - it should take input from the user and respond to changes in the model, updating both the model and view as required.

The reason for the three way split is that you can change just one of the MVC elements and have the app continue to work. You could change the model to spin the reels in a better way (more random) you could change the view from 2D to 3D (or iPhone to Mac) and you could change the event handling in the controller (e.g. add shake to trigger a spin). All independently.

Comment: ok what should i do now should i create different classes to handel all these things..or different methods following to these three(M,V,C) elements of design.

Comment: Well the model should be an NSObject descendent, although you may with to have several smaller models making up a bigger one... i.e. GameModel which has a PlayerModel and a WorldModel. The viewcontroller is as per a normal UIViewController, but Apple have strangely merged the View and Controller paradigms, hence UIViewController. You can create UIView subclasses to take a model and render it, then the UIViewController can update the model (and submodels) and then tell the view to update.

Comment: sounds tricky to me,can you suggest me to a good documentation for it

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on general MVC but not much on using it in Objective-c. I would start but looking at your game and saying "What can I describe without having to visually see it?", so in other words I can describe the Score without seeing it, it is just a number. The sequence of symbols in a reel is also something I can describe, so in this case my GameModel would have an NSInteger score; and three NSArrays containing my sequence of symbols.

Comment: Just keep looking at the game and try and extract the information that 'describes' the current state and put it in the model. Then your view can grab the score from the model, for instance, and show it on the screen.

Comment: You can try this, but I think it gets a bit complex for someone new to MVC.... http://www.slideshare.net/iamleeg/adopting-mvc-in-cocoa